# Overwrite function to recognize any dom changes including plugins like jquery

Tags: javascript

Which functions needs to be overwritten to recognize any DOM content changes (Application-Side), including plugins like jquery ? Do not suggest Mutation.

Comment: *Do not suggest Mutation* Why? That's how DOM changes are exposed!

Comment: Ist not cross-browser, its slow and deprecated.

Comment: I thought you were including [`MutationObservers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) when you said "mutation". They were designed to replace [Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events).

Comment: But its not included in ie jet...

Comment: Too many restrictions then. Your answer is, it's not possible.

Comment: What about overwriting innerHTML property, field whatever. its not possible ?

Comment: Maybe (never tried). But what about elements created/modified/inserted/moved with DOM methods like `appendChild`? You'll have to override a lot of stuff from the DOM API, *if* browsers let you do that.

Comment: yeah maybe you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this technique](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/08/06/css-selector-listeners/) that relies on CSS animation keyframes.

As said above, mutation specs are either deprecated or not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using jQuery itself and bind a handler to the `DOMSubtreeModified` event.

```
$(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
  console.log('changed');
})
```

There is actually [a warning on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified) that says it is deprecated. This is the only way I know of, though.