# Javascript call function when html inject finished onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I've got this situation:
There is a calendar script to pick a date. When the date is picked a function called onclick to make a select box available for time pick. Now its not like its display:none-->display:block, the select being generated by JS. My goal is to customize this select. For that I got a jquery script "custom.select" which just turns the select to spans. The problem is that if I add the call for this script to the onclick right after the calendar call it does not take. I am pretty sure its because at that stage the html for the select is not injected yet. If I call the custom.select function from the firebug console after the select is visible - it works just fine.
So the question is: how do I call it so it will do its magic on select box?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use delegation with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.classdynamic',function(){
        //do stuff here
    });
});
```

You should delegate event to the closest static container of your target element. This means changing `$(document).on('click','.classdynamic',function(){...});` 
by something like: `$('#staticContainer').on('click','.classdynamic',function(){...});`

Comment: This is what I did with your suggestion: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.td_calendar').on('click','#anchor1',function(){
   cal.select(document.forms['frmRequest'].startdate,'anchor1','yyyy-MM-dd');
   jQuery('#timeslots').customSelect();
  });
});` Its still not working.

Comment: '#anchor1' are using the same ids more than once in your page?

Comment: using on() doesn't change the fact that the elements don't exist yet when the script runs.

Comment: #anchor1 exists only once on the needed link. So as Christophe said elements do not exist yet.. Is there anyway to wait for the elements to appear before calling customSelect() ?

Answer (score 0):

Figuring out when elements are added is not an easy task. [I answered a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841440/overwrite-function-to-recognize-any-dom-changes-including-plugins-like-jquery/15841958#15841958).

The best way would be to have some control on the script that creates the select, and append your code to it. One way to achieve this is with Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) - not easy either.

With current browsers, the most straightforward way is to use setTimeout in a loop and poll the page until the element exists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this thanks to Christophe! I used the Selector Listeners script from here: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/08/06/css-selector-listeners/
It was even more complicated coz the parent was not present either )). So what I did was that I attached the listener to the onclick just after the calendar call lol. I needed to make another function though to make it work with the script, here is the code:

```
var doSelect = function(){
  jQuery('#timeslots').customSelect();
};
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.td_calendar').on('click','#anchor1',function(){
      cal.select(document.forms['frmRequest'].startdate,'anchor1','yyyy-MM-dd');
      document.getElementById('slots').addSelectorListener('#timeslots', doSelect);
  });
});
```